# How can I make my list to sync with the section (at the same page)

Tags: html, css

How can I make my `<li>` to sync with my `<section>`.
I want to click to my navigation bar button/text and directly drive me to the currently section by scrolling down. (at the same page). How can I do that or can I do the same thing in another way?. Btw I am new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anchor link for this.
The link to an anchor is noted in the href-attribute by placing a # after the file where the anchor is located and then writing down the name of the anchor. A link to an anchor could look like this:

```
<a href="#anchor">Click here</a>
```

The anchors for this could then look something like this:

```
<a name="anchor">Your text section</a>
```

Comment: Doesn't an `id="anchor"` get targeted by the `href="#anchor"`, too?

Comment: Yes, you can also use `id="anchor"`. In this case, the jump label does not necessarily have to be another `<a>` tag. 
For example `<span id="anchor">Your text section</span>`